# Acorn Electron to VGA/HDMI?

Tags: graphics, video, acorn, vga, electron

I am aware that there are answers regarding this but they do not seem to answer it for me.

A few years back I got a Acorn Electron and it works using the arial for video fine, but I would like to connect it to my monitor which has a VGA & HDMI input.

Is there a cheap converter or cable I can buy without me having to make something to convert one of the outputs on the electron to VGA/HDMI?

Thanks

Comment: As Tommy states, modern VGA monitors won't work without extra hardware. But you can use a SCART adapter cable to connect RGB to a TV or monitor with a SCART input. Since you're in the UK these TV/monitors should be readily available - you may already have one - and [here's a cable](https://www.retrogamingcables.co.uk/acorn-bbc-mirco-b-micro-master-electron-rgb-av-scart-cable-tv-lead-for-sale) that Tommy has already linked to. If you need more info I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 12):

It cost me something like $50 all up to connect my Electron to the TV using an RGB to SCART cable ([this one from eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/171309263925)) and an RGB to HDMI converter like the one pictured below:

[image: RGB to HDMI converter]

You can get this model from a bunch of different eBay sellers, under various different brand names, but they're all the same.  I've tested it out with MODE 0 - MODE 6, and it seems to consistently work well.  It also works well with my BBC Model B  The only time I've seen it fail is when playing *Firetrack* on the Electron, which does some tricky stuff with the video output to get more colours.

Answer (score 11):

The Electron outputs an analogue interlaced 625-line image, with a line rate of 15.625Khz.

HDMI is a digital input, so cannot comprehend the Electron's analogue output.

VGA is analogue but many monitors expect a line rate of 31 kHz. It's not impossible that your screen would be okay with 15.625Khz though, as that's the PAL standard, so you could at least have a try. The pinout of the Electron's monitor port is [here](http://www.acornelectron.co.uk/eug/27/a-rgbm.html) and a passive cable would work if your screen is compatible. I guess you'd need something like [this](http://coolnovelties.co.uk/coolnovelties/bbc-video-cables/51-bbc-micro-model-b-master-electron-rgb-scart-cable.html), [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2-METRES-SCART-Cable-to-SVGA-VGA-15-PIN-Male-2m-/351904598326?hash=item51ef260936:g:kycAAOSwHMJYHMuI) and [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/SCART-Cables/Psylins-Coupler-Female/B0009N1MX2).

Failing that, you'll need a scan doubler, which does exactly what the name says, taking a 15.625Khz input scan rate and outputting 31.25Khz, which is within the range VGA screens expect.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the RGB port on the electron is the same as the one on the BBC micro. This is digital RGB with composite sync at TTL levels. It also provides a handy 5V supply.

This can be adapted to RGB Scart with a few resistors to lower the signal levels and create the trigger voltages to tell the TV to use RGB scart mode. There is plenty of room in the shell of the scart plug for the resistors. You can find a schematic at http://mdfs.net/Info/Comp/BBC/Monitor/BBCtoTV.htm

Going to VGA however is more problematic in a couple of ways.

The first is that VGA normally uses seperate HSYNC and VSYNC signals, but the BBC micro/electron uses composite sync. There do exist sync separator chips like the LMH1981, which could in principle be used to split this up. I haven't tried them myself though.

The second is that the video timings are based on PAL TV and may be too slow for many VGA monitors.